# Need help finding the points positions

Tags: math

Here you can see a representation of the problem I need to solve
[http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/542/002yw.png http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/542/002yw.png](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/542/002yw.png)

I've two circles defined by their positions BS1 and BS2.

Now I need to get the position of the point A and the only data I've is the distance from point BS1 that is defined by its radius.

Can someone please tell me how can I find the coordiinates of point A?

Thank you very much

PD: I need to do the same with point B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity lets say, on your left side of the image you have a center c1, radius r1, and point A. On the right side center c2, radius r2 and point B..

A = ((s1-s2)/|s1-s2|)*r1 + s1

B = ((s2-s1)/|s1-s2|)*r2 + s2

Do not forget, this are vectors.. If you can not understand this equation, tell me and Ill explain it to you.